# How to get Mgr and Direct Report into from the same table?

Tags: sql

Say a data table has these four fields: EmpID, MgrID, First Name, Last Name, how do I write a query that gives me the Managers, their Employees, and their Manager (as in the Manager's Manager)? I tried for the life of me but can't figure it out.

Comment: Sample data and desired results always helps.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score -1):

You may assign those value into variables.

```
SELECT @MgrID := MgrID, @EmpID := EmpID FROM menagers WHERE firstName = 'menager_name'
SELECT * FROM menagers WHERE id = @MgrID
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = @EmpID
```

Customize table names into your environment.